# How to configure a proxy in a .Net Core Console App

Tags: .net, proxy, console-application, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

In previous `.Net` console applications we can avoid proxy `407` errors by including the following in `app.config`:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
</system.net>
```

`.Net Core` console app does not have `app.config` - how can we do the same?

Specifically for an Azure DocumentDB `DocumentClient`.

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent as you have to implement your own IWebProxy for .net-core.

Comment: I have seen examples of that for a HttpClient and for a WCF client but I am using Azure DocumentClient

Comment: NO_PROXY : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultproxy?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that for now `Azure`-oriented team didn't implement such feature. Here is a link to recent github issue for [Azure AD library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/552), which states that

> - Currently ADAL for .NET doesn’t support `WebProxy` configuration.
> - Please configure proxy at the system level. `Httpclient` used by Adal should be able to use it.
> - Production team has planned to add this function in future version, but currently they don’t have estimation time.

As far as one can see, there is no such feature available in [`Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Dn781842.aspx) namespace or in [`Microsoft.Azure.Documents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Dn781844.aspx) namespace, so for now you have to resolve it on system level. You can probably create a [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues) or contact the team on [MSDN](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=631655) or by [email](http://askdocdb@microsoft.com).

As for general `.Net Core` app, you can use the [`HttpClientHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.aspx) class' [`DefaultProxyCredentials`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.usedefaultcredentials.aspx) property, so the [code will be like this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/bef79311dde1f183530bb590182953973d9d3735/src/System.Net.Http/tests/FunctionalTests/DefaultCredentialsTest.cs):

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    // http call here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

VMAtm's answer did nothing for me. This fixed it for me on Core 3.1:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;    
using(var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync();
}
```

Comment: Holy thread bump Batman :) I don't even work for the company that had the proxy server any more :D

Comment: For .NET Core and .NET 5.0 take a look at env variable like NO_PROXY here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultproxy?view=net-5.0